# Passing variables through querystrings on jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm trying to pass a variable through from one page to another in my phone gap application. The function however, never seems to get called.

Heres what's building up the links:

```
$.each(data, function(index) {
    $("#listpetsList").append("<li><a href='javascript:loadPetdialog(" + data[index].AnimalCode + ")' data-rel=\"dialog\" data-transition=\"flip\"><img src='" + data[index].Picture + "'><h2>" + data[index].Name + "</h2><p>Type</p></li>");
});
```

Heres the loadPetDialog:

```
var editingId = 0

function loadPetdialog(id) {
    alert("hit");
    editingId = id;
    $.mobile.changePage("#select-pet-dialog");
}
```

However, it never seems to get hit

Comment: add listeners rather than using _inline_ JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use inline JavaScript with jQuery Mobile.

Do it like this:

```
$.each(data, function(index) {
    $("#listpetsList").append("<li><a data-custom='"+ data[index].AnimalCode + "' data-rel=\"dialog\" data-transition=\"flip\"><img src='" + data[index].Picture + "'><h2>" + data[index].Name + "</h2><p>Type</p></li>");
});

$(document).on('click', '#listpetsList li a', function(){ 
    editingId  = $(this).prop('data-custom');
    $.mobile.changePage("#select-pet-dialog");
});

var editingId = 0
```

Inline JavaScript has a tendency not to work or even misfire when used with jQuery Mobile. So it is best to bind click event to each listview element and get particular li element value when you click on it.

In my example I have bound click event to each listview elements. data[index].AnimalCode is saved as a custom data value. When you click on listview click event will trigger on selected listview element only, then we can easily find custom data value, add it to global variable and programatically change page.

Click event is bound in such way that it doesn't care if listview have or don't have inner content. It will work for any existing and future listview content.

### Update

I made a working example out of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/92XG5/

There's only one difference between this code and last weeks example.

Change this line:

```
    editingId  = $(this).prop('data-custom');
```

To this line:

```
    editingId  = $(this).attr('data-custom');
```

Comment: Thanks so much, again. Is there something not quite right with that document click event, it seems to be malformed in my IDE

Comment: Yeah I was missing a quote, I couldn't test it so I wrote it out of my head

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it kinda did, but i can't seem to see editiID being set correctly

Comment: I keep saying this, but you are an absolute gem of a person for explaining all these things to me.